# Finite number of topologies on an infinite set

Tags: general-topology

What type of topologies can be defined on an infinite set, such that the number of topologies of that type is finite?

For instance, is it possible to define only a finite number of Hausdorff spaces on any given infinite set? If not, imposing what additional conditions will make the number of such topologies finite?

Comment: Of course there is only one discrete topology and only one trivial topology.  However these facts are independent of the cardinality of the underlying set.

Comment: On a countable set one can already put infinitely many pairwise non-homeomorphic Hausdorff topologies.

Comment: Substantial additional conditions are needed to obtain a finite number of topologies on an infinite set.  One thought is R.L. Moore's 1920 theorem characterizing the unit interval as a [continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology)) (compact, connected metric space) with at least two points and no more than two non-cut points.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear since what counts as a "type of topology" is not realy well defind